# Go templating engine that also runs in the browser

Tags: javascript, go, template-engine

I'm developing a web application with Go on the server, and the router will use PushState, so the server will also have to be able to render my templates. That means that I'll need a templating engine that works with Go and Javascript. The only one I've come across so far is Mustache, but it doesn't seem to be able to handle lowercase properties of structs, and there also doesn't seem to be a possibility to provide custom names like JSON:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}
```

So, is there a templating engine that is available in both Go and JavaScript, and that can handle lowercase struct properties?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Lowercase properties in Go are privately scoped, so no 3rd party templating engine will be able to read them. You can maybe try converting your struct to a map and ensuring your key's are all lower cased to pass into the default Go template library?

Comment: I know they are private, but libraries like `encoding/json` and MGo (MongoDB), support using lowercase identifiers as in the example I gave in my original post, but as far as I know, there isn't a library for Mustache that can do that, and the default template library won't work because there isn't a browser port of it

Comment: `encoding/json` can't marshal properties with lowercase names. Your example is using uppercase struct properties.

Comment: It indeed can't marshal properties with lowercase names, but by adding the custom "tag" (or whatever it's named), you can specify a custom (lowercase) name, but as far as I know, there isn't a mustache library supporting that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments above state, you can't expect any 3rd party library to be able to read lowercase properties on your struct, but it appears you are trying to use tags to represent alternative representations of your struct (as you can with the `encoding/json` library).

What you can do is use something like `github.com/fatih/structs` to convert your structs to maps and then range through to lowercase all of your keys (copying the values and removing the uppercase versions) and pass it into `mustache.Render()` as your context. If you want to use struct tags like the `encoding/json` library does, you'd have to use the `reflect` package and write a struct-to-map function that takes into account the tags on the struct (basic example given in the documentation [here](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag)). There are some SO answers on how to write a struct-to-map function using reflection, which you can improve upon to add struct tag handling as you need.

To answer your question, I don't think this is something a current templating library does that also works with javascript, but it shouldn't be too hard to get working with mustache given the idea above.

Comment: Thanks for your help, with some help from the documentation and by looking at the `structs` library you pointed me to, I've written my own struct->map converter that can handle flags